# Get default member value of a type with reflection

Tags: f#

I have multiple types with a member of `memberName`

```
type User = {
    user_id: int
    username: string
    email: string
} with member this.memberName = "woo"
```

Then I want to have a function that can take a type argument of any type with that member and return the value of it.

My logic to this was to create a default instance of that type and check that way, but is returning a NullReferenceException

```
let inline GetMemberName< 'x when  'x: (member memberName: string)> () =
        let defaultType = Unchecked.defaultof<'x>
        ((^x) : (member memberName: string) defaultType)

GetMemberName<User> ()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `NullReferenceException` because you are accessing an instance member, but you are creating the instance using `Unchecked.defaultof` which returns `null`. This function is really an unsafe hack for interoperating with .NET, where any (non-value) type can have `null` - but this is not something you typically want in F#.

As far as I can see, you could turn this into a static member, which does not need an instance:

```
type User = 
  { user_id: int
    username: string
    email: string } 
  static member memberName = "woo"


let inline GetMemberName< 'x when  'x: (static member memberName: string)> () =
        ((^x) : (static member memberName: string) ())

GetMemberName<User> ()
```

If you actually wanted to initialize an F# type to a sensible default value, you could come up with a mechanism to do this using Reflection, but it would be hard and (in general) impossible as not all types have a reasonable default value.

That said, for records with integers and strings, something like this would be a start:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let flds = FSharpType.GetRecordFields(typeof<User>)
let vals = 
  [| for fld in flds -> 
        if fld.PropertyType = typeof<int> then box 0
        elif fld.PropertyType = typeof<string> then box ""
        else null |]
let user = FSharpValue.MakeRecord(typeof<User>, vals)
```

Comment: I had a big misunderstanding of what defaultof does. Getting the static member from the type is exactly what I wanted, thank you.